# Is it correct that if (1) then (2)?

Tags: inequality

Is it correct that if
$$3 < a < b$$
then 
$$a^b > b^a?$$

Comment: Yes, I think it is correct.

Comment: Maybe rewriting a^b as e^{b\ln(a) and b^a as e^{a\ln(b) will help

Comment: yeah it did help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check $a^{1/a}>b^{1/b}$, so can you prove that $x^{1/x}$ is decreasing in $(3,\infty)$?.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Should I differentiate a wrt x? or what? Sorry I'm confused

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. If you can prove that $\frac{d}{dx}(x^{1/x})<0$ when $x\in(3,\infty)$, then you will prove that $x^{1/x}$ is decreasing in $(3,\infty)$. As someone already suggested, expressing $x^{1/x}=e^{\ln x/x}$ may help to find the derivative.

Comment: thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Because $\ln$ is strictly increasing function, if we prove that $\ln a^b > \ln b^a$ we prove that $a^b > b^a$.

$\ln a^b > \ln b^a \rightarrow \frac{b}{\ln b} > \frac{a}{\ln a}$ which is true because $(\frac{x}{\ln x})'=\frac{\ln x -1}{\ln^2 x}>0$ if $x > e$